# Average presidential approval since 2000?

Tags: united-states, president, public-opinion

What is the average approval of the past 4 US presidents, from George W Bush to Joe Biden so far? I want the approval weighted by how many days the approval poll was taken.

Comment: What do you mean by 'how many days the approval poll was taken'?

Comment: Number File: How many days into the term? How many days the poll was open? Enquiring minds want to know...

Comment: I will re ask the question later with details

Comment: Try 100 days in office, mid-term, or any specific time that interests you.  I don't think the average rating is possible to construct unless there is such an agency that conducts the survey daily or at a regular interval., and publishes the results. this is an interesting question though.

Comment: @r13 Actually you do not need regular intervals. You just consider that the rating changes at the midpoint between two consecutive polls, and do the ponderated mean.

Answer (score 2):

[FiveThirtyEight](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/biden-approval-rating/) has an ongoing project which tracks Joe Biden's approval rating and compares it to each president since Truman on a day-by-day basis. I think that would probably provide the closest answer to what you're looking for; to get an "average" for a President's full term would require a lot of choices to be made as far as what polls to include, how to weight different polls (not just by the length of data collection, but also by the number of respondents, the method of contact, the pollster's history, etc.) and would likely be a significantly-difficult project in its own right.